# Android notification issue in some devices

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

I am new to android. In one of my application, I am using GCM service. It is working well in some devices. But the application gets crash on some devices when notification receives.

Following is my code..

```
private static void generateNotification(Context context, String message) {

long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
            context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, message, when);
    String title = "Application";
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    notificationIntent.putExtra("message", message);
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent intent =
            PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    notification.defaults|= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
    notification.defaults|= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;
    notificationManager.notify(0, notification); 

}
```

Showing some lines as strike through in this code like `new Notification` .

Can any one please tell me the issue ?

From googling I found that these functions are depreciated in new versions. So can I go ahead with new version code ?

Then my question is if I coded for new API's, is this application is compatable for older versions ? Current my `minSdkVersion=8 and targetSdkVersion=16`

Thanks in advance
Please help me

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to change the minSDKVersion and targetSDKVersion. You just need to add to your libs folder the latest "android-support-v4.jar". Then use the "NotificationCompat.Builder" class to show the Notifications. As this is the new version of Notification.